# Can the Groovy library for Jenkins be changed?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I am using the soapUI maven in Jenkins (am at the latest and greatest release)

There seems to be an issue with the groovy 1.8.5 which is fixed in the later versions of Groovy (2.1.5 for example).

Is there a way to change the underlying groovy library for Jenkins to 2.1.5.

I tried replacing the 1.8.5 in WEB-INF/lib with the 2.1.5 version and jenkins does not even start up

Appreciate any ideas/pointers.

Comment: Doesn't [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) for Jenkins provide that ability?

Comment: Not sure if that helps as the soapUI maven runs groovy under the hood. I am not writing any groovy scripts as part of the Jenkins job.

Comment: Well, in that case you can try customizing [maven-soapui-plugin](https://github.com/oysteing/maven-soapui-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml#L161) by modifying pom.xml to use latest version of Groovy (groovy-all).